# Begin work and commit work in different routes Express NodeJS

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express

I'm developing a rest api for a web application on nodejs and I use the pg module to connect to the postgresql database.

My question is this:

When a user began to change, for example, the tab of an article, a request was made to the node to perform the following query:

```
BEGIN WORK; 
Select * 
from article 
where art_id = 1 for update;
```

and when loaded into save execute the following query:

```
Update articles set .... where art_id = 1; 
Commit work;
```

Since the first query and the last query are in separate routes, the first query is executed successfully, but the last one is not executed because it is waiting for the first query to be done.

Has anyone had the same problem?

Here is my code:

Models:

```
exports.lock = function (callback) {
    const client = new Client(conString);
    client.connect();

    client.query('BEGIN WORK;SELECT * FROM teste where column_1 = 1 FOR UPDATE nowait ;',[], (err, result) => {
        client.end();
        if (err)
            callback(err,null);
        else
            callback(null,{success:true, data:result.rows});
    });
};

exports.unlock = function (callback) {
    const client = new Client(conString);
    client.connect();

    client.query('update teste set column_2 = $1 where column_1 = 1 ; commit work;',['teste222'], (err, result) => {
        client.end();
        if (err)
            callback(err,null);
        else
            callback(null,{success:true, data:result.rows});
    });

};
```

Controllers

```
router.get('/lock',function (req,res) {
    Art.lock(function(err, returnValue){
        if(err)
            return res.json(err);
        else
            res.json(returnValue);
   });
});

router.get('/unlock',function (req,res) {
    Art.unlock(function(err, returnValue){
        if(err)
            return res.json(err);
        else
            res.json(returnValue);
    });
});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: Adding the relevant code from your routes would make it much clearer to understand. Without the code it's not obvious where the problem is.

Comment: Models and Controllers code added.

Comment: This is most likely due to poor connection management and/or configuration. You can try [pg-promise](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise), which will handle the connections for you automatically.

Comment: Is it even possible to do it this way?? I'm not familiar with postgre but imagine multiple users requests /lock route then how would postgre know when the users request /unlock which query belongs to which?? I think that `begin work` and `commit work` needs to be used within same connection. Once you call `client.end()` you can't `commit work` in another connection. I hope i'm not mistaken though.

Comment: `BEGIN/COMMIT` need to be executed within the same connection. That's how transactions work.

Comment: In a situation where I want to lock a record in the database while someone makes changes to that record, what is the best way?

My idea is when someone clicks the Modify Article button so that others can view article information, but as long as the changes are not sent to the database anyone else can modify that article.